# How to set Size of colum and row of tablelayoutpanel in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I want to create a tablelayoutpanel use **C#**. This is my codes:

```
private void create_table()
    {
        table = new TableLayoutPanel();
        table.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        table.RowCount = rows; //10
        table.ColumnCount = cols; //10


        table.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;

        this.table.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);

        TableLayoutRowStyleCollection rowStyles = this.table.RowStyles;
        TableLayoutColumnStyleCollection colStyles = this.table.ColumnStyles;

        foreach(RowStyle rowStyle in rowStyles)
        {
            rowStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
            rowStyle.Height = 10;
        }
        foreach (ColumnStyle colStyle in colStyles)
        {
            colStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
            colStyle.Width = 10;
        }
        this.Controls.Add(table);
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Did I miss something?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5uG8.png)

Thanks.

Comment: `table.RowStyles.Clear(); table.ColumnStyles.Clear(); for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100f)); }`, the same for the Columns, except you use `ColumnStyle` instead of `RowStyle`, not convertible -- The percent value set to `100f` is not a mistake, this instructs the Control to automatically calculate the percentage based on the number of Columns / Rows added, which of course must match the number of Row/Column Styles

Comment: Note that the Size of the TLP you have set will cause the last Row and Column to have a size different than the others, because the size of a Cell needs to consider the border and, eventually, the padding